# Javascript idioms this that vs this self

Tags: javascript, closures

I've been writing JavaScript for a bit and have now seen code using the idiom

```
var that = this;
```

and

```
var self = this;
```

Used to gain access to `this` through closure scope. At this point `var self = this` seems somewhat more common.

My question is which of these two idioms is truly the convention?
Since they do exactly the same thing, are there advantages/disadvantages to either?

Comment: I don't think either is _truly_ the convention, but `self` does seem to have become more common, and is certainly easier to understand contextually than `that`.

Comment: .bind(this) and you don't have to worry about such foolishness

Comment: @rlemon `.bind` is not really cross browser (old IE) and is considerably slower in resource intensive situations, but yeah - bind is an interesting correction.

Comment: But it is sexy and avoids `that = this`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum neither is a real issue, they can be solved by the common sense custom implementation, which is included in every library anyway. Why duplicate this "idiom" when you can DRY it behind a function?

Answer (score 6):

**Update 2018**: You should use *neither* and prefer *arrow functions* that have lexical `this` scoping.

---

Original:

They are **both** idiomatic.

An experienced JavaScript programmer will know *exactly* what's going on when reading either.

It's just a variable naming thing - there is no *empirical* reason to choose one over the other - they function exactly the same and they're both common in big code bases of common open source libraries.

There is no reason to use one over the either. The important thing is to **pick one and stick with it**, and when you're joining a new code base - stick to whichever they were doing.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2698831/1348195) related question in StackOverflow notes that `self` might have a really minor shortcoming where it refers to `window` in some browsers - so instead of getting a ReferenceError you'd get a silent error. However - this should not be the case anyway if you use a linter.